# Updgrading to rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I just ran

```
$gem upgrade rails
```

It seemed to go smoothly (updated 23 gems, no errors, etc...)

when i run

```
$rails -v
```

It tells me I have 2.3.5.   What gives?

Comment: you use rvm? did you try restarting the shell?

Comment: lol!  restarting terminal (i'm on a mac)  fixed the issue.  Thanks!

Comment: ...if you want to fill in an answer with you suggested i can give it my approval ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a comment - instead of "restarting the terminal" you may issue a "hash -r" command in such cases. It causes your shell to "forget" all the cached paths.